# Connecting to a host listed in ~/.ssh/config when using Fabric

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm having trouble with [`Fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/0.9.1/api/contrib/project.html) not recognizing hosts that I have in `~/.ssh/config`.

My `fabfile.py` is as follows:

```
from fabric.api import run, env

env.hosts = ['lulu']

def whoami():
    run('whoami')
```

Running `$ fab whoami` gives:

> [lulu] run: whoami
>
> Fatal error: Name lookup failed for
>   lulu

The name `lulu` is in my `~/.ssh/config`, like this:

```
Host lulu
     hostname 192.168.100.100
     port 2100
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/lulu-key
```

My first thought to solving this is adding something like `lulu.lulu` to `/etc/hosts` (I'm on a Mac), but then I have to also pass in the identity file to Fabric - and I'd rather keep my authentication (i.e. `~/.ssh/config`) separate from my deployment (i.e. `fabfile.py`).

As well, incidentally, if you try to connect to a host in the hosts file, `fabric.contrib.projects.rsync_project` doesn't seem to acknowledge 'ports' in the `hosts.env` (i.e. if you use `hosts.env = [lulu:2100]` a call to `rsync_project` seems to try connecting to `lulu:21`).

Is there a reason Fabric doesn't recognize this `lulu` name?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Since version 1.4.0, [Fabric uses your ssh config](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#ssh-config) (partly). However, you need to explicitly enable it, with

```
env.use_ssh_config = True
```

somewhere near the top of your fabfile. Once you do this, Fabric should read your ssh config (from `~/.ssh/config` by default, or from `env.ssh_config_path`).

One warning: if you use a version older than 1.5.4, an abort will occur if `env.use_ssh_config` is set but there is no config file present. In that case, you can use a workaround like:

```
if env.ssh_config_path and os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(env.ssh_config_path)):
    env.use_ssh_config = True
```

Comment: The answer originally started with "The accepted answer is outdated" [since it documented pre-1.4.0 behaviour]. I've removed this preface, since my answer was accepted instead ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Note that this also happens when the name is not in `/etc/hosts`. I had the same problem and had to add the host name to both that file and `~/.ssh/config`.

Answer (score 5):

**update**: This Answer [is now outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685171).

---

Fabric doesn't have support currently for the .ssh/config file. You can set these up in a function to then call on the cli, eg: fab production task; where production sets the username, hostname, port, and ssh identity.

As for rsync project, that should now have port setting ability, if not, you can always run local("rsync ...") as that is essentially what that contributed function does.

Comment: Set env.key_filename to the full path of the private key. Also if you run into trouble, see http://code.fabfile.org/issues/show/265 for a few issues around this.

Comment: Yup, it's got support now. (though it was pre 1.0 when I commented) Noting for later readers.

Answer (score 4):

One can use following code to read the config (original code taken from: http://markpasc.typepad.com/blog/2010/04/loading-ssh-config-settings-for-fabric.html):

```
from fabric.api import *
env.hosts = ['servername']

def _annotate_hosts_with_ssh_config_info():
    from os.path import expanduser
    from paramiko.config import SSHConfig

    def hostinfo(host, config):
        hive = config.lookup(host)
        if 'hostname' in hive:
            host = hive['hostname']
        if 'user' in hive:
            host = '%s@%s' % (hive['user'], host)
        if 'port' in hive:
            host = '%s:%s' % (host, hive['port'])
        return host

    try:
        config_file = file(expanduser('~/.ssh/config'))
    except IOError:
        pass
    else:
        config = SSHConfig()
        config.parse(config_file)
        keys = [config.lookup(host).get('identityfile', None)
            for host in env.hosts]
        env.key_filename = [expanduser(key) for key in keys if key is not None]
        env.hosts = [hostinfo(host, config) for host in env.hosts]

        for role, rolehosts in env.roledefs.items():
            env.roledefs[role] = [hostinfo(host, config) for host in rolehosts]

_annotate_hosts_with_ssh_config_info()
```

Comment: fabric 1.2+ uses `ssh` library (`paramiko` fork): `try: \n from ssh.config import SSHConfig \n except ImportError: \n from paramiko.config import SSHConfig`

Comment: SSH library has been merged back into Paramiko, e.g. `from paramiko.config import SSHConfig`