# Python Fabric : Executing functions on different hosts with different passwords, in the same script

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I'm currently trying to automate a deployment process, involving 3 different machines :

- userA@hostA, pwdA
- userB@hostB, pwdB
- userC@hostC, pwdC

Here's the scenario I would like to execute, using Python's Fabric library (to which I'm new) :

```
def deploy():
    execute(taskA, hosts=[hostA])
    execute(taskB, hosts=[hostB])
    execute(taskC, hosts=[hostC])
```

I've tried to set the variable  `env.passwords`  like this:

```
env.passwords = {'userA@hostA:22':pwdA, 'userB@hostB:22':pwdB, 'userC@hostC:22':pwdC}
```

But it makes the SSH connection hanging.

My current workaround is to modify the variables `env.user` and `env.password` before each call to `execute` (I could also do that at the beginning of taskA, taskB and taskC). I really do not find that very elegant, and totally outside of Fabric's spirit.

If someone has ran into such situation, found him/herself with a hanging SSH connection while trying to use the `env.passwords` dict, I'm all yours ! And of course, if anyone already managed to make a more elegant multi-host-password handling, I would be glad to hear about any hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to keep your ssh details in `~/.ssh/config` and have Fabric use that.  See

- Leveraging native SSH config files
  http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/usage/execution.html#ssh-config
- Connecting to a host listed in ~/.ssh/config when using Fabric
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9685171

Comment: Hello, @jq170727, thanks for your answer and sorry for my late reply !

I confirm that your answer works well, when we handle security via a public-key/private-key pair !

However, in my context, I have to stick to the unsecure way, and have no control over that for the moment. Yet I found a workaround for my problem, which I will describe in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

As said in my comment above, using the *use_ssh_config* variable works well. But in case you SSH with a password, Fabric currently doesn't handle per-host/per-user/per-password connection (which is normal, since using SSH passwords is considered as insecure)

That's why I dug into Fabric's source code, and added that new "feature". [Here](https://github.com/mourtisma/fabric) is my repository if you want to have a look. Basically, I used the `env.roledefs` variable, which lists roles as dictionary entries. And each role has a list of hosts, a user, and a password. Now, if you want to execute a task in one or more hosts (which have different usernames and passwords), there are two ways to do it:

- Annotating the task with the decorator `@complete_roles('role1',
  'role2')`
- Using the function `execute(task, complete_roles=['role1', 'role2'])`

Just be sure to have 'role1' and 'role2' as keys in `env.roledefs`

If you want to have more info about my contribution, just check the two latest commits. I know, my code is not the cleanest...